# vbs equivalent to \*. (.bat files)?

Tags: vbscript

I decided to rework my app and I'm "translating" all the .bat files to .vbs files almost done but the bat script below is a big problem for me

```
@ECHO OFF   
move "..\Styles\DropWall\*.jpg" "..\..\chrome\OPCEN\images\WALLPERSONA\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg"     
move "..\Styles\DropWall\*.png" "..\..\chrome\OPCEN\images\WALLPERSONA\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg" 
exit
```

I already used this to move a known file, sure I'm missing something

```
Option Explicit
Dim Fso 
Set Fso= WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Fso.MoveFile "..\Styles\DropWall\AB.jpg", "..\..\chrome\OPCEN\images\WALLPERSONA\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg"
```

Comment: NEVER use relative paths when programming. This gets the Program Files folder `Msgbox CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(&h26).Self.Path`

Comment: sorry to say I have no alternatives to the relatives paths

Comment: Rubbish. Why write deliberate buggy code that CAN ONLY work if certain assumptions are true.

Comment: I'm not a programmer I'm a skinner but I had an original idea to customize the Firefox UI well all the codes must run inside the Firefox profile and the paths are relative to the chrome folder. All working using the bat files converted to exe (to avoid the black console) the only big problem were the false positives (18out of 60 antivirus) that's why I decided to use .vbs + ,hta files like they are

Comment: @frankell If you are not a programmer why are you asking questions on a programmer website? You will be better off looking for a VBScript tutorial if you are interested in learning the scripting language.

Comment: ,@catcat + @ Lankymart thanks the same

Answer (score 1):

VBScript `FileSystemObject` methods don't have a direct equivalent for "copy any .jpg file from the source directory as this particular output file in the destination directory". You can move *all* .jpg files from a given source directory to a given destination directory (without renaming the files):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
fso.MoveFile "C:\source\*.jpg", "C:\destination\"
```

but for moving any file with a matching extension you need something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\source").Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "jpg" Then
        f.Copy "C:\destination\bar.jpg", True
        f.Delete
    End If
Next
```

The combination of `Copy` and `Delete` is recommended, because `Move` (or `MoveFile` for that matter) doesn't allow for replacing existing files, meaning that if there were more than one matching file in the source folder, moving the second file would raise an error.

Comment: actually I already tried to use your first suggestion  " \* " but was not working (see the title)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            the second one give me thiis error: object required : "

Comment: Honestly @ansgar-wiechers it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @frankell My first code snippet is not a suggestion, but meant to illustrate the limitations of that approach. Please go find a VBScript tutorial if you want to continue. Right now you are *way* out of your depth.

Comment: ok ok thanks the same